# Create of all possible combinations from 2 sets or lists as a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, set, combinatorics

I have 2 sets (could be a list as well though not sure if it would make much difference)

```
set1 = (w1,w2,w3,w4)
set2 = (r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7)
```

I want to create all possible combinations as a **dictionary of sets** with elements of `set1` as keys and `set2` as values. The max length of the values of a set is `n`.

So for example, for `n=3`:

Sample output

```
Comb1 = {w1:(r1,r2), w2:(r3), w3:(r4,r5,r6), w4:(r7)}
Comb2 = {w1:(r6), w2:(r1,r3), w3:(r2), w4:(r4,r5,r7)}
Comb3 = {w1:(r2), w2:(r1,r3), w3:(r4,r6), w4:(r6,r7)}
.
.
.
.
```

Here, in each combination, max length of a set (or value) is 3.

I was looking at the itertools library but not sure how to sample variable lengths as set. I also considered random sampling without replacement from set2 but I won't get all possible combinations from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
import copy
set1, n = ('w1','w2','w3','w4'), 3
set2 = ('r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','r6','r7')
def combos(d, c = []):
   if not d:
      yield c
   else:
      for i, a in enumerate(d):
         if (c1:=len(c)) + 1 <= (l1:=len(set1)):
            yield from combos(d[:i]+d[i+1:], c+[[a]])
         if ((_d:=d[:i]+d[i+1:]) or c1 == l1) and c and len(c[-1]) + 1 <= n:
            yield from combos(_d, [*c[:-1], c[-1]+[a]])
         
r = combos(set2)
print([dict(zip(set1, map(tuple, next(r)))) for _ in range(100)])
```

Output (first 100 results):

```
[{'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r6', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r7', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r4', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r4', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r5', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r7', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r4', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r4', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r5', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r6', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r4', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r4', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r6', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r7', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r5', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r5', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r4', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r7', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r5', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r5', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r4', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r6', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r5', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r5', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r5', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r7', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r6', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r6', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r4', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r7', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r6', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r6', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r4', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r5', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r6', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r6', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r5', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r6', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r7', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r7', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r4', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r6', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r7', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r7', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r4', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r5', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r7', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2',), 'w3': ('r3', 'r7', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4',), 'w4': ('r5', 'r6', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4',), 'w4': ('r5', 'r7', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r5', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r7',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r5', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r6',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4',), 'w4': ('r6', 'r5', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4',), 'w4': ('r6', 'r7', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r6', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r7',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r6', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r5',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4',), 'w4': ('r7', 'r5', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4',), 'w4': ('r7', 'r6', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r5', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r7', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r6',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r7', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r5',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r4'), 'w3': ('r5',), 'w4': ('r6', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r4'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r7',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r4'), 'w3': ('r5',), 'w4': ('r7', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r4'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r6',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r4'), 'w3': ('r6',), 'w4': ('r5', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r4'), 'w3': ('r6', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r7',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r4'), 'w3': ('r6',), 'w4': ('r7', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r4'), 'w3': ('r6', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r5',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r4'), 'w3': ('r7',), 'w4': ('r5', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r4'), 'w3': ('r7', 'r5'), 'w4': ('r6',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r4'), 'w3': ('r7',), 'w4': ('r6', 'r5')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r4'), 'w3': ('r7', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r5',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5',), 'w4': ('r4', 'r6', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5',), 'w4': ('r4', 'r7', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r4', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r7',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r4', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r6',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5',), 'w4': ('r6', 'r4', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5',), 'w4': ('r6', 'r7', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r6', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r7',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r7', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r6', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r4',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5',), 'w4': ('r7', 'r4', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5',), 'w4': ('r7', 'r6', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r4', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r7', 'r4'), 'w4': ('r6',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r6', 'r4')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3'), 'w3': ('r5', 'r7', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r4',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r5'), 'w3': ('r4',), 'w4': ('r6', 'r7')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r5'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r6'), 'w4': ('r7',)}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r5'), 'w3': ('r4',), 'w4': ('r7', 'r6')}, {'w1': ('r1',), 'w2': ('r2', 'r3', 'r5'), 'w3': ('r4', 'r7'), 'w4': ('r6',)}]
```

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll try it out and mark it as the solution. I am very new to generator functions so I'll have to read up on them but could you tell me how do you get the length of the generator in such a case?

Comment: @cppnoob In order to get the number of results a generator can produce for an input, the entire generator has to be loaded into memory. In this case, running `all_combos = list(combos(set2)); l = len(all_combos)` will give you the total number of combinations, but depending on the size of `set2`, the code might hang for a long time, until all the combos are produced.

Comment: Thanks! Could I run it as while(True) rather than loading all of them in memory?

Comment: @cppnoob Yes, for example: `while (combo:=next(r, None)) is not None: pass #do something with combo`. The `while` loop will exhaust the generator eventually and allow you to be more memory efficient.